# Get URL of the file streamed by InputStream

Tags: java, jar, stream, resources

Models.jar contain the file cmudict, this jar file is added as class path to the project

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("edu/cmu/sphinx/language/cmudict");
```

Above statement accesses the file *cmudict* Stream, but I want to print the complete URL of the file location, which also includes the location of Models.jar file.

How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved very easy:

```
URL resource = this.getClass().getResource();
```

Have a look at the API for more informations
@see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-

Comment: Problem is another bundle **X** provides Model.jar file as Stream, and I have to create a bundle that accesses this jar file i.e. provided by **X** and get data from it.